# How to deal with categorical data in K-means clustering method when we have mixed data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, categorical-data

I am using k-means method to cluster some buildings according to their Energy Consumption, Area (in sqm) and Climate Zone of their location. Climate Zone is a categorical variable. Values can be A,B,C or D. It should be transformed to a numerical one, so there are two options. First, LabelEncoder and second, get_dummies. When I use each of those, results are totally different. I would like to ask which method is more correct to use?

I guess because "get_dummies" creates more dimensions for each categorical variable, should gives more decision power to the categorical variable, which is not usually favorable. On the other hand, seems that using LabelEncoder is also not totally right. Because we can say "A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4" OR "A=3, B=2, C=4, D=1" OR many other options. This may change the results even though they are indifferent. So I am not sure which one is better to be used.

Any statistical or mathematical explanation is appreciated.

Thank you

**What I mean by get_dummies?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The standard k-means algorithm isn't directly applicable to categorical data, for all kinds of reasons.  The sample space for categorical data is discrete, and doesn't have a natural origin.  A Euclidean, or Manhattan, distance function on such a space isn't really meaningful.  What is the 'distance' between red, yellow, orange, blue, and green?  You may want to consider using a technique called 'Cosine similarity'.  Cosine similarity is a metric used to measure how similar multiple strings of text are, or even entire documents are, are irrespective of their size.  Mathematically, it measures the cosine of the angle between two vectors projected in a multi-dimensional space.  The cosine similarity is advantageous because even if the two similar documents are far apart by the Euclidean distance (due to the size of the document), chances are they may still be oriented closer together.  The smaller the angle, higher the cosine similarity.

Here are a couple links that may help you.

https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/cosine-similarity/

https://sites.temple.edu/tudsc/2017/03/30/measuring-similarity-between-texts-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

If there is a logical order of the categories (i.e. colour `Red` is more similar to category `Yellow` than to category `Green`) you can apply weighted values to categories. But this is a typical "false" category feature (because it can be decomposed in a vector of numerical features, the way you have shown).

If the problem is related to real categorical features each category has the same distance to each other. You can set a fixed distance for any category feature depending on the logic importance (weight) of this category for clustering.

If all of your features are categorical or mixed have a look at [k-mode or k-prototype](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes) algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add another answer here.  I think my first answer was pretty much correct.  However, I did figure out a way to use K-means to cluster text, so I will share that here, as I am looking for feedback regarding the 'correctness' of this technique.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["This little kitty came to play when I was eating at a restaurant.",
             "Merley has the best squooshy kitten belly.",
             "Google Translate app is incredible.",
             "If you open 100 tab in google you get a smiley face.",
             "Best cat photo I've ever taken.",
             "Climbing ninja cat.",
             "Impressed with google map feedback.",
             "Key promoter extension for Google Chrome."]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

true_k = 8
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=1000, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    print

print("\n")
print("Prediction")

Y = vectorizer.transform(["chrome browser to open."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)

Y = vectorizer.transform(["My cat is hungry."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)
```

Result:

```
Top terms per cluster:
Cluster 0:
 eating
 kitty
 little
 came
 restaurant
 play
 ve
 feedback
 face
 extension
Cluster 1:
 translate
 app
 incredible
 google
 eating
 impressed
 feedback
 face
 extension
 ve
Cluster 2:
 climbing
 ninja
 cat
 eating
 impressed
 google
 feedback
 face
 extension
 ve
Cluster 3:
 kitten
 belly
 squooshy
 merley
 best
 eating
 google
 feedback
 face
 extension
Cluster 4:
 100
 open
 tab
 smiley
 face
 google
 feedback
 extension
 eating
 climbing
Cluster 5:
 chrome
 extension
 promoter
 key
 google
 eating
 impressed
 feedback
 face
 ve
Cluster 6:
 impressed
 map
 feedback
 google
 ve
 eating
 face
 extension
 climbing
 key
Cluster 7:
 ve
 taken
 photo
 best
 cat
 eating
 google
 feedback
 face
 extension
```